# useEffect doesn't work correctly even when setting the dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a useEffect function filters out two arrays but for some reason it isn't working correctly. If I remove the dependency array then the brings back the correct data but it keeps on looping.
[image]

I've then added the dependency array back in, but then it comes back empty. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (extras.length && pkg ? .id) {
    setVisibleExtras(
      extras.filter(({
          availableOnTariff
        }) =>
        availableOnTariff.some(({
          id
        }) => id === pkg.id)
      )
    );
    console.log('visible extras', visibleExtras);
  }
}, [extras, pkg]);
```

Comment: `setVisibleExtras` updates the state of `extras` which then triggers the `useEffect` again resulting in an infinite loop

Comment: @TobiasS. Is there a way to set the state but then to also stop the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If `setVisibleExtras` changing `extras` it will always trigger whole useEffect again... if its your case, use callback function in `setVisibleExtras` instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (extras.length && pkg ? .id) {
    setVisibleExtras((extras) =>
      extras.filter(({
          availableOnTariff
        }) =>
        availableOnTariff.some(({
          id
        }) => id === pkg.id)
      )
    );
    console.log('visible extras', visibleExtras);
  }
}, [pkg]);
```

Comment: Using a callback method doesn't seem to work as-well. The console log doesn't execute....

Comment: Can you provide where you get setVisibleExtras and extras then?

Comment: Sure. It's set to be an empty array at the start of the component:  const [visibleExtras, setVisibleExtras] = useState([]);